# Device vanishing after jump to code

Tags: iphone, assembly, arm

Working on a project that is supposed to take a prepatched iBSS image and jump to it using the limera1n base. Here is the code:

```
@constants -----------------------------------
.pool
.set    BOOTROM_A4,         0x00342e34
.set    a4_jump_to,         0x5a5d
.set    a4_usb_wait_for_image,  0x4c85
.set    a4_aes_crypto_cmd,      0x686d
.text
@main code -----------------------------------
.code 16
_start: .global _start
MOV R7, PC
B   entry_point
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP
NOP

entry_point:
@LSR    R7, #2
@LSL    R7, #2
LDR R1, =a4_usb_wait_for_image
LDR R0, =loadaddr
LDR R1, =max_size
@ boot that image
MOV R0, #0
LDR R1, =loadaddr
MOV R2, #0
LDR R3, [R7, #8]
BLX R3 @ device vanishes from USB pool after this
@-----------------------------------------------------
memcpy:
_memcpy_loop:
LDRB    R3, [R1]
STRB    R3, [R0]
ADD R0, #1
ADD R1, #1
SUB R2, #1
CMP R2, #0
BNE _memcpy_loop

BX  LR
@-----------------------------------------------------
.end
```

The point, is to be able to USB send a custom loader to the device early on in the boot chain, using limera1n or stage-2 SHAtter. The only problem itself is that once the code hits the last BLX R3, the device stops responding to USB commands, and therefore I am unable to upload the second stage.

Comment: Sorry, is this gas? And it doesn't require any `_asm` directives? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I like this stuff very much. Hoping to get myself a good book on it. Good luck in getting the answer.

Comment: The best way to learn is to just jump into the freezing cold water instead of walking in slowly.

Comment: Show me where the cold water is? Can you elaborate a bit more? You meant going through tutorials online or just come up with a project and start push'ing and mov'ing?

Comment: It sounds great. Where / with what to start as far as writing a basic OS in assembly goes?

Comment: It is assembly for the iphone because the purpose is to run specialized operating systems on the iphone early on in the boot process

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @auselen I am trying to jump to unsigned code in the early stage of the boot chain of an iphone (before the bootloader is jumped)